# Вычисление площади фигуры

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Необходимо вычислить площадь двумерной фигуры (треугольника или квадрата).

```
public double GetArea()
{
    double area = default(double);

    for (int i = 0; i < dots.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        area += dots[i].X * dots[i + 1].Y - dots[i].Y * dots[i + 1].X;
    }

    retuen area / 2;
}
```

Расположение точек задаю в часовом порядке или наоборот, но, по-моему, площадь вычисляет неправильно.

Comment: Замкните многоугольник: `area += dots[dots.Length - 1i].X * dots[0].Y - dots[dots.Length - 1].Y * dots[0].X; return Math.Abs(area/2);`

Comment: `default(double)`

Answer (score 4):

Вы забыли добавить в сумму последний отрезок замкнутой ломаной:

```
public double GetArea()
{
    double area = default(double);

    for (int i = 0; i < dots.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        area += dots[i].X * dots[i + 1].Y - dots[i].Y * dots[i + 1].X;
    }
    // Не забываем, что ломаная должна быть замкнутой:
    area += dots[dots.Length - 1].X * dots[0].Y - dots[dots.Length - 1].Y * dots[0].X;

    return Math.Abs(area) / 2;
}
```

Формула у вас правильная: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid).
Существует еще немного иной, но столь же верный (и чуть более быстрый) вариант: [algolist.manual.ru](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/polygon/area.php)

Comment: неправильно. У ТС - правильно - векторное произведение.

Comment: @Igor Нет, правильно. Более того - более оптимально, поскольку 2 операции сложения и только 1 умножение. Если раскроете скобки и выполните суммирование - сами убедитесь. Ответ был плохим, поскольку дело было вовсе не в формуле.

Comment: да, Вы правы, я не прав.